# UR5 use moveit interface to move robot

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-industrial, universal-robot, ur5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I would like to move the UR5 Robot with the move_group python interface. I used the interface with the pr2 Robot and it's working fine.
Here is the interface Tutorial page: http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/pr2_moveit_tutorials/html/planning/scripts/doc/move_group_python_interface_tutorial.html

When i would like to use the python interface with the UR5 then I do it like this:

```
roslaunch ur5_moveit_config demo.launch
python move_group_python_interface_tutorial.py
```

The robot is loading in RVIZ perfectly. When it starts the interface it's looking like this:

```
============ Starting tutorial setup
[ INFO] [1421497007.277703461]: Loading robot model 'ur5'...
[ INFO] [1421497007.277819143]: No root joint specified. Assuming fixed joint
[ INFO] [1421497007.716290571]: Loading robot model 'ur5'...
[ INFO] [1421497007.716347402]: No root joint specified. Assuming fixed joint
[FATAL] [1421497007.980622919]: Group 'left_arm' was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "move_group_python_interface_tutorial.py", line 238, in <module>
    move_group_python_interface_tutorial()
  File "move_group_python_interface_tutorial.py", line 76, in move_group_python_interface_tutorial
    group = moveit_commander.MoveGroupCommander("left_arm")
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/moveit_commander/move_group.py", line 51, in __init__
    self._g = _moveit_move_group_interface.MoveGroup(name, "robot_description")
RuntimeError: Group 'left_arm' was not found.
```

Of course, i know that i haven't got a left arm on the ur5. But what else i have write in there? Or is there any better idea how to move the robot with moveit?

Thank you very much for your help =)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201177/ur5-use-moveit-interface-to-move-robot/) by [Jan Moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21179/jan-moritz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2015-01-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Note: I'm assuming you are using the `ur5_moveit_config` package from the `universal_robot` repository from ROS-Industrial.

---

I don't really understand what you are asking.

First you say:

> Of course, i know that i haven't got a left arm on the ur5 [..]

which is true. But then:

> But what else i have write in there?

Which doesn't really make sense. To solve this 'problem', you'll just have to make sure the code is using the correct group name, which is defined in the [ur5.srdf](https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot/blob/93ba9e5e7090d07ef1c610daa33aba2012100ace/ur5_moveit_config/config/ur5.srdf) file (more precisely, on [lines 12 to 14](https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot/blob/93ba9e5e7090d07ef1c610daa33aba2012100ace/ur5_moveit_config/config/ur5.srdf#L12-L14)). In this case, that name is `manipulator`, as is the case for all MoveIt configurations that were created by the ROS-Industrial project.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3